# How to select or exclude multiple elements with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have something like the following:

```
<div id="div1" style="display: block;">
text
</div>

<div id="div2" style="display: none;">
text
</div>

<div id="div3" style="display: none;">
text
</div>
```

When a certain event happens, I want to hide all but one div. So, for instance, I might want to show div2, while hiding div1 and div3. The problem is that the number of divs is arbitrary, so I can't simply go:

```
$("#div1").css("display", "none");
$("#div2").css("display", "block");
$("#div3").css("display", "none");
```

Because there might be one div or there might be four.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Comment: what kind of event?  Is there anything in common with those divs?  Do they have the same parent?  Are there other elements(besides the divs) that are siblings to those divs?

Comment: Can you add a class to the divs?

Comment: @wirey - for example, supposed that I have a number printed out on the page corresponding to each div (so if there are four of these divs, then there would be the numbers 1-4) and then when a number is clicked I want the corresponding div to become visible. Not exactly what I'm doing, just an example. I could make them have the same parent, yes.

Comment: @tymeJV - sure, ID's, classes, whatever works..

Comment: @Nate Don't forget to accept whichever answer you used :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, lets add a class to your divs

```
<div id="div1" class="someDiv" style="display: block;">
text
</div>

<div id="div2" class="someDiv" style="display: none;">
text
</div>

<div id="div3" class="someDiv" style="display: none;">
text
</div>
```

Assuming your numbers are in a list:

```
<ul>
<li>1</li>
<li>2</li>
<li>3</li>
</ul>
```

And the jQuery

```
$("ul li").click(function() {
    var divNum = $(this).text();
    $(".someDiv").hide();
    $("#div" + divNum).show();
});
```

Answer (score 3):

[**Here's an example jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/LBYPf/).

I wasn't really sure what kind of event you wanted or if you'd allow us to use classes, so I went with `change()`:

**jQuery:**

```
$('select').change(function(){
   $('div').hide();
   $('div#' + this.value).show();
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<select>
    <option>1</option>
    <option>2</option>
    <option>3</option>
</select>

<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">2</div>
<div id="3">3</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Give them a common class, for example, use for the click event:

```
$('.foo').click(function() {
   $('.foo').not(this).hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

you're looking into jQuery selectors..
you can use wildcards, select multiple elements, first and last and much more..

```
$("#div1, $div2") (selects multiple divs)
$("$divX > first) (all elements with the same id, gets the first)
$("[id^=div]") (get's all elements starting with id div)
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Comment: Follow the link for details. (Summary: the place is riddled with inaccuracies, misrepresentations, bugs, and internal inconsistencies.)

Comment: I didn't know that..many times I got half accurate info from them, but I just put it aside as browser stuff...I will not use them no more :) Tx!

Answer (score 0):

You may do it this way, on your event function:

```
function(){
    $('#div' + $(this).val()).show().siblings('div').hide();
}
```